# single staff for percussion

Tags: theory

From my past experience, single staff is usually used for one percussion instrument at a time (any percussive instrument). For the transcription in the picture, which percussions do the notes represent?[image: Steven Mcwhirter]!

Comment: Possibly bongos. I mean, I have a book (it's at home, can't remember the title) that uses that notation, IIRC.

Comment: Since the title is Swiss ruffs this may just be on snare. Could be below the line Is left hand above the line Is right. Large note heads are full strokes and small are grace notes. Just guessing here. Who’s signature is in the bottom corner. Idpb is a pipe band. So yeah drum and pipes. This is the drum part.

Comment: @ b3ko: I agree, not sure about Swiss ruffs ... I can't decipher the first word. :)

Answer (score 1):

This notation is just for l. and r. hand:

you can play and practice this on any drum pad and other percussion instrument like snare, bongos, congas etc.

For more information:

*Learn How To Play The Drag Ruff.*

*The drag ruff is a foundational rudiment that is required to play several more advanced patterns. It's fairly basic on its own, but is still usable in a wide variety of drumming styles. The drag is perfect for ghost notes within drum beats, or as a lead in for simple drum fills. Here is how the rudiment is written in drum notation:*

https://www.freedrumlessons.com/drum-lessons/drag-ruff.php

For more information: